# apex trigger issue with dynamic soql

Tags: apex, trigger, dynamic-soql

custom object: schedule_c fields: Runway_C and date_C Runway_c is a picklist field having track1 and track2 values. date__c field is datetime field.

i having the the records in schedule object e.g airline: kingfisher flight k-101 runway: track1 date: 22-02-2014 11.00 AM

the same records like above...now i created one trigger to prevent the same schedule to insert.i used .adderror to show the validation error while inserting and updating new record.

this trigger is not returning any rows, i dont know what i am missing..

```
trigger runwaynew1 on Schedule__c (before insert, before update) {    
    String whereCond = '(';

    for(Schedule__c s : Trigger.new) {        
        Datetime dt = s.Date__c;
        system.debug('s.date' +s.Date__c);
        String formatedDt = dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'z\'', 'GMT' );
        //string time1 = string.valueof(formateddt);
        //string time2 = time1.substring(0,10)+' '+ time1.substring(11,19);
        //system.debug('time2' +time2);
        whereCond += '(Runway__c = \''+s.Runway__c+'\' and Date__c = '+formatedDt+')';        
    }

    whereCond +=')';
    system.debug('whereCond:'+whereCond); 

    String query = 'Select Id from Schedule__c where '+whereCond;

    system.debug('------------query--------------'+query);
    system.debug('------------databasequery-------------');

    List<Schedule__c> sList = Database.query(query);

    system.debug('------------sList:--------------'+sList);

    for(Schedule__c s : sList) {        
        s.adderror('Flight Already Scheduled on the Runway');
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your `whereCond` is most likely the cause. Can you provide the output of `system.debug('whereCond:'+whereCond);` which will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than a single record, your trigger will error.  You have no 'AND' or 'OR' between the different parts of the WHERE Clause if there is more than a single record.

Also, are you sure there is already something with that exact same value?  Keep in mind that the time has to be exact down to the seconds or even finer for it to show up in your query.  You probably should be doing a range instead of an exact time.